# ¿Porqué no se ejecuta la validación en los setters de mi clase?

Tags: c#

No me dispara los errores. Cuando ingreso 1 puerta por ej y 22 dolares costo diario lo toma como bien y se anade correctamente el vehículo, sera que en el program tengo que hacer el catch para cada uno

```
 public string Matricula
    {
        get { return matricula; }
        set { matricula = value; }
    }
    public string Marca
    {
        get { return marca; }
        set { marca = value; }
    }
    public string Modelo
    {
        get { return modelo; }
        set { modelo = value; }
    }
    public int Año
    {
        get { return año; }
        set { año = value; }
    }
    public int Cantidadpuertas
    {
        set
        {
            if (value < 2)
                throw new Exception("El vehiculo tiene que tener minimo 2 puertas");
            else
                cantidadpuertas = value;

        }
        get { return cantidadpuertas; }
    }
    public int Digitos
    {
        get { return digitos; }
        set { digitos = value; }
    }
    public double Costodiario
    {
        get { return costodiario; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 25)
                throw new Exception("El costo diario minimo es de 25 dolares");
            else
                costodiario = value;
        }
    }
    public Vehiculos(string mat, string mar, string mo, int a, int cant, int dig, double costo)
    {
        matricula = mat;
        marca = mar;
        modelo = mo;
        año = a;
        cantidadpuertas = cant;
        digitos = dig;
        costodiario = costo;
    }

    public virtual string MostrarPolimorfico()
    {
        return "\n"+"MATRICULA : "+ matricula.ToUpper().Trim() +"\n"+ "NUMERO MATRICULA : "+ digitos +"\n"+ "MARCA : "+ marca.ToUpper().Trim() +"\n"+ "MODELO : " + modelo.ToUpper().Trim() +"\n"+ "AÑO DE FABRICACION : " + año +"\n"+ "CANTIDAD DE PUERTAS : "+ cantidadpuertas  + "\n"+ "COSTO DIARIO DE ALQUILER EN DOLARES : " + costodiario;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Francop, por favor agrega mas detalles a tu pregunta. De la forma que está no es posible entender cual es el problema.

Comment: Ese código está incompleto. Faltan la declaracion de los campos, la clase y lo mas importante el constructor que es donde creo que está el problema

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz ahi edite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en tu constructor

Estás asignando los campos directamente y no llamando a los setters.

Prueba con lo sgte:

```
public Vehiculos(string mat, string mar, string mo, int a, int cant, int dig, double costo)
{
    Matricula = mat;
    Marca = mar;
    Modelo = mo;
    Año = a;
    Cantidadpuertas = cant;
    Digitos = dig;
    Costodiario = costo;
}
```

De esta manera llamarías a los setters de cada campo y el código con la validación se ejecutaría como parte de la construcción de la instancia

Comment: ahora si, solo que tengo un problema y es que si tengo los dos errores me salta solo el primero

Comment: Solo se lanzará la excepción en `Cantidadpuertas` luego de esto el programa se detiene. Si lo que estás buscando es validar de forma interactiva (es decir validar lo que un usuario ha ingresado a la UI y mostrar mensajes de validación) no deberías usar excepciones

Comment: ah ok es que nos ensenaron eso, muchas gracias!

Comment: Es por eso que se recomienda que los nombres de los campos que pertenecen a las propiedades comienzen con un underscore: `int _año; double _costodiario;`. Para evitar este tipo de confusión.